# Issue with Windows Store app CommandParameter; doesn't bind to UIElements or their properties?

Tags: data-binding, command, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, commandparameter

The past couple of hours I've been trying to pass a `GridView`'s `SelectedItem` to a `CommandParameter` with all sort of crazy ways from different binding styles to crazy-hacky converters.
Each time the command is executed the parameter appears null. Also when I tried in the code-behind to retrieve the button's `CommandParameter`, it returned as null.

I don't know if this is really the case, that they have dropped out this feature also from Windows Store apps, or if this is caused by my fail update with Visual Studio 2012 update 2.

If there's anyone, who might know a solution to this problem, please share. And if you happen to know that this is really how it is, I'd also like to know that.

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see some of the code? Are you passing it with a button? Are your bindings working? Like, do you have a textblock or something that displays the SelectedItem so you know you're accessing it? Can you have your GridView two-way bind to a property in your ViewModel and have the CommandParameter bind to that?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this scenario using an `ElementName` binding:

```
<GridView Height="600" x:Name="gv" />
<Button Command="{StaticResource MyCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=gv, Path=SelectedValue}"
        Content="Click me please, I like it" />
```

Full example code: https://github.com/finnigantime/Samples/tree/master/examples/Win8Xaml/GridViewItem_CommandParameter